# How to display individual digits of integer input?

Tags: java

I am working on an assignment which prompts the user to input an integer, and displays that integer with the digits separated by spaces, and provides the sum of those digits. I have this working, but my individual digit display is form the last digit to the first. How can I make it display the digits from first to last?

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class SeparateAndSum{
   static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int num, temp, sum;

      System.out.print("Enter a positive interger: ");
      num = console.nextInt();
      System.out.println();

      temp = num;

      sum = 0;

      do
      {
         temp = num % 10;      
         sum = sum + num % 10; 

         num = num / 10;       
         System.out.print(" " + temp + " ");
      }while (num > 0);

      System.out.println("The sum of the digits = " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: `int temp = (int)(num / Math.Pow(10, Math.Log10(num)));` will return first digit. Think about how to use it in a loop.

Comment: You code seems ok to me.

Comment: Note that `"JAVA programming, I'm stuck"` is a terrible title for a StackOverflow question as it tells us nothing whatsoever of use. We already know you're stuck, else you wouldn't be asking a question, and we already know it involves Java since your question has a Java tag. In the future, please consider using much more informative question titles, ones that summarize your actual problem. Doing this will help you get better help.

Comment: Thanks the next time I want help writting a title I'll be sure to ask you.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use the `String#valueOf(Integer)` method.

**Example**

```
int input = 12345;

String inputStr = String.valueOf(input);

for(char c : inputStr.toCharArray()) {
    // Print out each letter.
}
```

Comment: We haven't gotten to arrays yet.

Answer (score 0):

if you use the method String.valueOf(12345)

you can easily reverse the String with the method in this library:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#reverse(java.lang.String)

```
StringUtils.reverse(String.valueOf(input));
```

Comment: I went to the site and reversing the string would be great, except I need to have a space between each digit. I'm still researching...

Comment: You can simply use your method and at the line you print the numbers, add them to a string, then you can reverse it. 
         String s = s + " " + temp

Comment: I have been trying so many different things that I am more confused than before. What I'm thinking of now is to use the method string like you suggested and reverse it BEFORE I extract the digits and sum them. But I'm not familiar with using the string method. I looked at that site but I don't understand how to get the input as a string, reverse it and then cast it to an interger. I don't know if I'm making this harder than it has to be or if I just can't find the steps in my book.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
import java.util.*;

public class SeparateAndSum{
   static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

   int num, temp, sum;

   System.out.print("Enter a positive interger: ");
   num = console.nextInt();
   System.out.println();

   temp = num;

   sum = 0;
   ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();

   do
   {
      temp = num % 10;      
      sum = sum + num % 10; 

      num = num / 10;       
      values.add(temp);
   }while (num > 0);
   Collections.reverse(values);
   Iterator<Integer> it = values.iterator();
   while(it.hasNext()){
       System.out.println(" "+it.next()+" ");
   }
   System.out.println("The sum of the digits = " + sum);
 }
}
```

BTW you should have to import `ArrayList` etc.

Comment: We haven't gotten to arrays yet.

Comment: Then I would recommend you to use `String` input and then manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend putting the number into a String and then reading it, parsing it, and use the number however you want. As follows,

```
int input = 12345;
String inputString = input + "";

int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
    sum += Integer.parseInt(inputString.charAt(i) + "");
}

System.out.println(sum);
```

However an alternative way, not as pretty is..

```
int input = 12345;

int sum = 0;
while (input > 0) {
    int i = (input + "").length() - 1;

    int n = (int) (input / Math.pow(10, i));
    input -= (int) (n * Math.pow(10, i));

    sum += n;
}

System.out.println(sum);
```